# Break, exit en evento Genexus

Tags: eventos, genexus, events

Buen día, soy muy nuevo en Genexus 17, tengo dos consultas

1. cómo puedo hacer validaciones de campos vacíos en un web panel? en una transacción se coloca en las reglas como Error("texto") if campo.isEmpty(); pero en un web panel no me deja hcer lo mismo, cuál sería la solucion
2. Como segunda opción a mi primer problema realicé un sub Evento pero cuál sería la forma de salir de ese evento mientras está validando, por ejemplo
   Si campo1=vacío
   **Salga**
   Si campo2=vacío
   **Salga**
   pero no se como decirle a Genexus que "*salga*" me dice que exit es para loops, return, me regresa a la página anterior, y según veo no existe el break, no se que mas intentar

Answer (score 1):

La forma sería utilizando los eventos [IsValid](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/wiki?6564,IsValid%20Event%20for%20Web%20Applications) o [ControlValueChanged](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/wiki?22676,ControlValueChanged%20event).

**IsValid** se ejecuta al salir del campo (si es de texto o número) o al seleccionar una opción (si es combobox o radiobutton).

**ControlValueChanged** se ejecuta al cambiar el valor del campo (pero si se mantiene el valor original, pese a no ser válido, no se ejecuta el evento).

El ControlValueChanged parece más eficiente ya que solo ejecuta ante cambios en los valores y se puede combinar con una validación en el evento que utiliza esos valores (Evento Enter, evento de Usuario o el que necesites) para no enlentecer la ejecución, especialmente si las validaciones tienen llamadas a procedimientos.

En el siguiente ejemplo se puede ver el uso de ControlValueChanged. Si el valor del campo cambia, valida que sea un valor válido (en un procedimiento IsValid que por ejemplo verificaría que esté en una determinada tabla)

```
Event &Variable1.ControlValueChanged
    if IsValid(&Variable1)
        Msg('El valor de Variable1 es inválido')
    endif
EndEvent
```

En este ejemplo, valida que el campo no esté en blanco al salir del mismo, pero solo da el mensaje de error, no impide que se llamen a otros eventos.

```
Event &Variable2.IsValid
    if NOT &Variable2.IsEmpty()
        msg('La variable2 no puede estar en blanco')
    endif
EndEvent
```